# Rails 6 plugin: Create custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I created a rails plugin with `rails plugin new my_plugin`. I want my plugin to create a route which maps to a controller/method inside my plugin.

I followed this [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/plugins.html#routes) on how to create a route from within a plugin. But it's for Rails 2.x and I'm using Rails 6, so I ended up with the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ActionController::Routing (NameError)
```

---

How can I have my plugin create a route that maps to a method inside my plugin? Something like:

```rb
# A new route set by my plugin
post '/my_plugin', controller: 'my_plugin_controller', action: 'do_something'
```

Answer (score 0):

After studying [ActiveStorage's](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-1-stable/activestorage/config/routes.rb) routes and the [Rails Engine docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) turns out the key to success is:

```rb
module Blorgh
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

By inheriting from the `Rails::Engine` class, the plugin notifies Rails that there's an engine at the specified path, and will correctly mount the engine inside the application, performing tasks such as adding the app directory of the engine to the load path for models, mailers, controllers, routes, and views.